# How to request a job for every first day of the month with GNU date syntax in BASH?

Tags: bash, date, cron, gnu

I have a cronjob in a YAML file that currently conducts a check on data from '5 days ago' to 'yesterday'.

I was wondering what could replace the '5 days ago' with something that would always call on the first day the month.

```
"START=$(date --date=\"5 days ago\" '+%Y%m%d');END=$(date --date=\"yesterday\" '+%Y%m%d')
```

^^ current format

I've had a look [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-get-yesterdays-tomorrows-date.html) but there doesn't seem to be an answer unless i've overlooked something.

Any advice welcome

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43264/13796

Answer (score 4):

Simply output year and month from the current date, and instead of the current day just print the 1st one:

```
START=$(date '+%Y%m01')
```